# MYSQL Database Structure - Arrays?

Tags: php, mysql

I've read multiple places that you shouldn't store arrays in a mysql db. So I thought I'd ask how I should go about doing this:

I'm writing a basic task management app in php/mysql, and I want to have projects and tasks. A task is a single object, where a project is an object that holds multiple tasks. So I already have the tasks working, I have a task table with id, name, dueDate columns. My next step is the projects.

My plan was to have a project table with id, name, dueDate, and taskID columns. The taskID column would either hold an array of task IDs or possibly just a string with comma delimiters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not have `projectID` as a foreign key in your task table?

Comment: multiple values in a single field defeats the purpose of having a relational database. Splitting those multiple values into their own dedicated child table is called normalization, and you should read up about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a one-to-many relation in MySQL. You would have tasks that hold the id of the project they are assigned to. So to find the tasks associated with the project, you would simply query for all tasks that are holding the project id. Does that sound right?

Comment: Ahhhhhh...DUH! Simple, graceful solution. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Tasks(id, name, dueDate, **ProjectID**)
Projects(id, name, dueDate)

The ProjectID column is an and of a foreign key and the Proejcts' table id column is the other one.

Answer (score 0):

If there can be a different number of task ID's per id/name record then two options. The first is to use XML instead of SQL. The second is to create two tables. On that holds the id, name and due date and then a second that just has id and taskID. id in this second column is a foreign key referencing id in table 1 and taskID is a single taskID. For example:

Table 1:

```
id | name | dueDate
-------------------
1  | bob  | '2012-08-16'
2  | fred | '2012-08-17'
```

Table 2:

```
TableID | TaskID
-----------------
1       | 1
1       | 2
1       | 3
2       | 1
2       | 2
```